# View com IEnumerable e EntityFramework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, entity-framework

Possuo uma entidade de Vendas e a mesma possui diversos campos (*IdItem, DataVenda, ValorVenda, TaxaDesconto, IdCliente, IdCategori*a e etc).

Já possuo todas as Views funcionando para esta entidade(***CRUD***).

Agora vou criar uma nova View em que serão apresentado os Clientes de forma agrupada com seus respectivos totais.

***Perguntas:***

**1)** Necessito criar um Model especifico para representar esta View?

**2)** No banco de dados consigo visualizar estas informações utilizando a seguinte query => `select b.IdCliente, b.NomeCliente, Sum(ValorVenda) as ValorVenda, Count(*) as TotalItens from TabVendas a inner join TabCliente b on a.IdCliente = b.IdCliente`, como fazer esta mesma Query via EntityFramework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Será muito importante a geração de um `ViewModel` (que seria uma nova classe que representa `SQL`). O dado **tipado** é mais simples utilizar em um tela com MVC **ASP.NET** e também com **ORM Entity Framework**.

O **Entity Framework** gera tranquilamente essa `SQL` você só precisa usar os métodos de extensão corretamente (*Where, Join, GroupBy, Count no Select*, etc)  para gerar essa mesma SQL que você trouxe na sua questão ou então utilizar SQL Raw como desse exemplo.

***Exemplo:***

---

***ViewModel***

```
public class DadosViewModel
{        
    public int IdCliente { get; set; }
    public string NomeCliente { get; set; }
    public decimal ValorVenda { get; set; }
    public long TotalItems { get; set; }
}
```

***SQL Raw***

Você pode utilizar assim em sua variavel de Context (Entity Framework):

```
 string SQL = " select b.IdCliente, b.NomeCliente, Sum(ValorVenda) as  ValorVenda, ";
 SQL += " Count(*) as TotalItens from TabVendas a inner join TabCliente b ";
 SQL += " on a.IdCliente = b.IdCliente";

 IList<DadosViewModel> ListaDadosViewModel = Contexto.Database
                                              .SqlQuery<DadosViewModel>(SQL).ToList();
```

***SQL pelo Entity Framework***

```
IList<DadosViewModel> ListaDadosViewModel = Contexto
         .Vendas
         .GroupBy(c => c.Cliente)
         .Select(s => new DadosViewModel {
            IdCliente = s.Key.IdCliente,
            NomeCliente = s.Key.NomeCliente, 
            ValorVenda = s.Sum(v => v.ValorVenda),
            TotalItems = s.LongCount()
         })
         .toList();
```

***View***

```
@model IEnumerable<ViewModels.DadosViewModel>

@foreach(ViewModels.DadosViewModel item in Model)
{

}
```

Comment: Acho que seria interessante para o autor da pergunta ter uma resposta com código concreto. Poderia por favor colocar alguns exemplos?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez fiz os exemplos, é que estava produzindo o mais simples para ele entender!

Comment: Pode colocar mais coisas. As respostas não apenas atendem a um autor de pergunta, como a toda a comunidade que usa o site. +1.

Comment: Ok, @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Answer (score 3):

> 1 - Necessito criar um Model especifico para representar esta View?

Não necessariamente. As funções de agrupamento e totalização podem ser feitas na *View*, se você quiser.

> 2 - no banco de dados consigo visualizar estas informações utilizando a seguinte query:

```
select b.IdCliente, b.NomeCliente, Sum(ValorVenda) as ValorVenda, Count() as TotalItens 
from TabVendas a 
inner join TabCliente b on a.IdCliente = b.IdCliente
```

> como fazer esta mesma query via EntityFramework?

```
var totalVendas = db.Vendas.Include(v => v.Cliente)
                    .GroupBy(v => v.Cliente)
                    .Select(g => new {
                        IdCliente = g.Key.IdCliente,
                        NomeCliente = g.Key.NomeCliente
                        ValorTotalVenda = g.Sum(v => v.ValorVenda),
                        TotalItens = g.Count()
                    })
                    .ToList();
```

Lembrando que a *View* deve receber isso como:

```
@model IEnumerable<dynamic>
```

Ou você pode tipar o objeto de retorno como *ViewModel*:

```
var totalVendas = db.Vendas.Include(v => v.Cliente)
                    .GroupBy(v => v.Cliente)
                    .Select(g => new RelatorioVendasItemViewModel {
                        IdCliente = g.Key.IdCliente,
                        NomeCliente = g.Key.NomeCliente
                        ValorTotalVenda = g.Sum(v => v.ValorVenda),
                        TotalItens = g.Count()
                    })
                    .ToList();
```

E então:

```
@model IEnumerable<SeuProjeto.ViewModels.RelatorioVendasItemViewModel>
```

Comment: Show de bola!!! vou adaptar a sua apresentação ao meu projeto. Obrigado mais uma vez pela ajuda!!!!